# Directus - Permissions on M2M collection

Tags: collections, permissions, m2m, directus

I'm looking for a way to restrict an M2M collections according to the following rules:

- Customers can only delete, edit or view their own projects
- Professionals can only view projects assigned to them

[image]

Here's my schema:

[image]

And here are my permissions:

[image]

[image]

With that configuration professionals can see all projects, but I need to restrict them to their owns, what is the best way to do it with permissions?.

Right now I'm using this call:

```
http://directus.local/_/items/projects?filter[professional][eq]=6
```

Comment: hello @Mario Rojas, did you able to solve problem, i was having similiar case as well and wanted to ask if you already found the solution ?

Comment: hi @Hayra, not yet! I'd been using hooks but it's just a workaround